# areablock in block is not working properly

Tags: pimcore

as i understand, nested areablock are possible since long. but something's not working.
lets say we have two areas, one called 'nested' and one called 'text'.

this is view.php for text:

```
<div>
    <?php echo $this->wysiwyg("content_wysiwyg"); ?>
</div>
```

this is view.php for 'nested':

```
<div>
    <?php while($this->block('index')->loop()) { ?>
        <div>
            <?php echo $this->areablock('index_block'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

i create a page, and insert the areas like this:

> nested 1
>
> > text 1
> >
> > nested 2
> >
> > > text 1.1

when i preview the page everything is fine. but when i view the same page without pimcore_preview=true text 1.1 is not displayed. the divs are there so the template gets included, but the content is missing.

what's going on here?

Comment: Is there a way you can clarify this better?

Comment: what should i clarify? i'll do anything to solve this bug, it drives me crazy.
you can try it yourself. just make two areas, put the code in, make a page with text nested inside an areablock. the text will not get included except in the preview.

Comment: i have no hope that this bug gets fixed any time soon. has anybody an idea for a workaround?
i'm quite new to pimcore but an experienced developer. i can't understand how you are supposed to do certain tasks without areablocks in blocks!
i need a block because the order of elements of it are arrangeable.
i need an areablock inside the block, because the content is arbitrary.

any help and ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem today.
Viz. I had problem with visibility of any editable item in front end.
You need to clear your cache and that's it.